# How to temporary store in form data in .NET core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.Net Core and I am creating a mock Flight booking app. On my home page, I have a search form to find a flight.

On submitting my form it goes to my `SearchResultsController` and then to my `Search()` action where I will run a search query.

What's the best way to pass the parameters through to this controller action for use in the `Search()` action method?

All the methods I've seen this far have involved creating new models but I don't want to save the searches to my database as it's not information that needs retaining. Having come to form a rails background I would use the parms hash which is a temporary data store.

Form:

```
 <form asp-controller="SearchResults" asp-action="Search" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fromAirport">Flying from:</label>
                    <select asp-for="AirportId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfAirports, "AirportId", "AirportCode"))" class="form-control">

                    </select>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="toAirport">Flying to:</label>
                        <select asp-for="AirportId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfAirports, "AirportId", "AirportCode"))" class="form-control">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <label for="fromAirport">Departure Date:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="date" />
                    <br />
                    <label for="fromAirport">No. passengers:</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Search Flights</button>
                </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Put them in hidden fields on your form.

Comment: I don't want them to be hidden fields though as the user is choosing their flight options? I'm basically trying to pass this form data to the Search() action

Comment: Use a view-model. Models don't have to be stored in the database!

Comment: Ahh ok. I have actually just managed to pass the data through by including a name="date" and name="passengers" within the form itself. Is it better to use a model?

Comment: Models encapsulate the data to keep it organized. You don't _have_ to use a model.

Comment: If you don't want to create a model,you can try to use `FormCollection`,and get form data from it.

Comment: thanks, `IFormcollection` works